# Can I edit/update my verified google apps script web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, verification

I have a, verified by Google, google apps script web app, which handles various google drive,google docs/sheets/slides functions (4 scopes).

Since verification, I have not edited or updated the script, but now need to make some changes.

If I stay within the scopes declared, will my app remain verified, or will any change require a re-verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your script is verified, your app should remain verified even if it is modified (as long as you stay within the scope).

You only need to verify it again when the modifications done belongs to a different scope which is not listed on the initial verification.

Similar behavior goes with normal script when done by a gmail account. Executing it at first will require you to verify the account with the scopes used. Once verified and authorized, it will now bypass this verification process the next time you execute the script, unless you add a new method that belongs to a new scope which requires you to do the verification process again.

#### Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

Comment: Many thanks. That gives me confidence to start making changes. I have no need to work outside my existing scopes. I did read the page you linked to, three times, but found no mention of editing/updating a verified web app ;)

Comment: Hi @MetricRat, the documentation linked actually was just for the scopes. Since you need to declare the scopes every verification, you need to re-verify the app if an additional scope is added. 

If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Need a chance to test it out! All works fine after updating. Thank you.